# Using ResourceLoader.GetString method to retrieve resources with dots in the key

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps

I'm using ResourceLoader.GetString to get string resources from my .resw file. I'm able to retrieve resources without a dot in the key, but ones with a dot come back as an empty string. For example:

```
var rl = new Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.ResourceLoader();
rl.GetString("HelpText"); // gets the string "Help"
rl.GetString("Forget.Text"); // gets "", even though it's defined in resw file as "Forgotten"
```

I've tried replacing the dot with various other characters:

```
rl.GetString("Forget_Text");
rl.GetString("Forget:Text");
rl.GetString("Forget-Text");
```

No luck. All the examples on MSDN skilfully avoid mentioning this little issue, so I'm a bit stumped. Can anyone help?

Comment: This question, and its answer, also apply to UWP (and UWP with Xamarin.Forms) getting from a resx file.  If you use `System.Resources.ResourceManager.GetString(_name_)`, and _name_ contains a period or dot, even if a valid resource exists, null will be returned.  In Xamarin Android and .NET 4.5.2 the period retrieves the resource, the forward slash does not. Hopefully this comment makes this answer discoverable via search. Moral of the story, don't use periods in resource names.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It *is* actually accessed via a forward-slash:

```
rl.GetString("Forget/Text");
```

Comment: Thanks, that solved it.  I've loved windows phone development, but these undocumented "quirks" which are fundamental, cause many expensive hours of frustration. What would windows phone dev be without Stack Overflow.  Honestly Nicrosoft this is very poor form, no wonder there's an App Gap on this platform.

Comment: Actually the dot/slash 'quirk' is documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-resources/localize-strings-ui-manifest

Comment: Yeah, that documentation is dated 2017, so well after the original question. Nice that they finally added something though!

Comment: Great job! Microsoft. Be proud of yourself.

Answer (score 0):

How would you deal with a final dot?  For example:

`ResourceManager.GetString("My string.")`

The forward slash works fine for dots embedded within the string, but not a final dot.  Eg, this results in a compile error (error : PRI175: 0x80070057 - Processing Resources failed with error: The parameter is incorrect.):

`ResourceManager.GetString("My string/")`

The only way I've found around that is to substitute something for the dot before putting it into the resw file. For example, this looks weird but it works:

`ResourceManager.GetString("My string0x2e")`

Thank you.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30981545)