# Xamarin.Forms UWP with .NetStandard 2.0 and null resources

Tags: xamarin.forms, uwp, resx, .net-standard-2.0

We are currently moving our Xamarin projects from PCL to .Net Standard 2.0, also core library project format. Most things works well. We use resx-files in the core project for localization. This works fine on iOS and Android.

On UWP I get `null` as value, if I try to access the string ressources

```
var buttonText = AppResources.Cancel; // => null
```

The PCL version the same code worked well. Is there some initialization needed?

On debug I can see that the resource manager has a `null` ResourceSet, but `_WinRTResourceManager` is filled.

[image]

Comment: I have attempted to create `Xamarin.Forms UWP` with `.NetStandard 2.0`.But I could not reproduce your issue and `AppResources` works in my side. Could share a simple sample  that can reproduce this issue ?

Comment: Thank. I created a small test app and the, UWP works. The `ResourceManager` looks like in the Full app (null for resource set and filled WinRT part). I will write the solution, if I find the difference betweeen the test and full app.

Comment: I found the reason. We use German (de-DE) as default language. As soon as I change the default langugage in `Package.appxmanifest` from the default value `en-US` to `de-DE` the resources from .Net Standard library could not be read. The fix is, to define explixit the `NeutralResourcesLanguage` for the .Net Standard library (to the same as UWP project). This can be done in manually created AssemblyInfo.cs (do not forget to turn off auto generation of AssemblyInfo) or declare this info in one of the exsisting classen `[assembly: NeutralResourcesLanguage("de-DE")]`

Comment: I am having this same problem when updating to NET Standard 2.0 from PCL, except my default language is still set to `en-US`. The suggested `NeutralResourcesLanguage` fix in `AssemblyInfo.cs` didn't seem to fix it. Any ideas?

Comment: @kspearrin Do you have the same _default_ language in your .Net standard and UWP projects?

Comment: @WebDucer Thanks, that fixed it! I set `<NeutralLanguage>en-US</NeutralLanguage>` in my .NET Standard class lib and it started working.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Finally I found the reason.

By converting PCL library to .Net Standar normally the file `AssemblyInfo.cs` is not there. So the neutral language definition get lost.

We use German (de-DE) as default language. As soon as I change the default langugage in `Package.appxmanifest` from the default value `en-US` to `de-DE` the resources from .Net Standard library could not be read.

The fix is, to define explixit the NeutralResourcesLanguage for the .Net Standard library (to the same as UWP project). This can be done in manually created AssemblyInfo.cs (do not forget to turn off auto generation of AssemblyInfo) or declare this info in one of the exsisting classes with `[assembly: NeutralResourcesLanguage("de-DE")]`.

After this fix the resources from .Net Standard library are used correctly also in UWP.

Comment: This worked for me but just a note. If you have multiple .NET Standard Libraries, you have to add a default language to all of them else it won' work.

Comment: In addition to the step above I also needed to overcome the dot/slash 'quirk'. This will also return null if using a period in the name of the resx resource. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28505933/using-resourceloader-getstring-method-to-retrieve-resources-with-dots-in-the-key