# ResourceManager returning null for default culture

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, localization, resx, .net-standard

I'm working on a Xamarin Forms app, using a .NET Standard library. I've used the `TranslateExtension` as mentioned in [the docs](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/advanced/localization/#Localizing_XAML). I've added three resource files:

- `AppResources.resx` (with matching code-behind file, auto-generated)
- `AppResources.nl.resx` (Dutch translations)
- `AppResources.fr.resx` (English tranlations)

When debugging the (UWP) app, I can't get the default culture (English) to be displayed. The following line returns null:

```
ResMgr.Value.GetString(Text, ci);
```

I've add some lines for debugging, and the other two languages do return the translated value:

```
ResMgr.Value.GetString(Text, new CultureInfo("nl")); // OK
ResMgr.Value.GetString(Text, new CultureInfo("fr")); // OK
ResMgr.Value.GetString(Text, new CultureInfo("en")); // returns null
```

What could possibly be the cause of this?

Things I've tried:

- I've copy-pasted the key across all resource files, so I've ruled out misspelling the resource key.
- I've tested `"en-GB"`, `"en-US"`, `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`.
- I've changed the default lanuage in the appxmanifest from `en-US` to `en`.

Answer (score 4):

[On UWP, watch that your resource name does not have a period in it.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28505933/using-resourceloader-getstring-method-to-retrieve-resources-with-dots-in-the-key).

You also likely need to tell the UWP project what its default language is.  This can be done in the .csproj in the top `<PropertyGroup>` element (the one with no conditions) by adding `<DefaultLanguage>en-US</DefaultLanguage>` (using the proper culture for your scenario).

Don't forget to set the `[assembly: NeutralResourcesLanguage("en-US")]` as well for the assembly containing the resources - this is required for .NET Standard 2.0 and likely PCL.

Comment: Note that if your resource name does have a period in it, replace it w/ a forward slash,   eg:   ResourceManager.GetString(key.Replace(".", "/"), <culture info>)

Comment: @Wes: You'd need to condition this replacement for UWP only, as other platforms would then fail to find the resource. Better to not use periods at all and not worry about making per-platform adjustments.

Comment: For anyone else struggling with this, another caveat is the dot/slash 'quirk', when accessing resources with a dot in the name. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28505933/using-resourceloader-getstring-method-to-retrieve-resources-with-dots-in-the-key

Answer (score 0):

Well it seems like you've got resx files for "nl" and "fr" (which you've said works fine) but you don't have one for "en". If you're trying to get the English value like that, I would think you need an "en" file the same way you do for "nl" and "fr"

Comment: Are you sure? In the past, I've worked with resource files and it would use the default AppResources.resx file, if I recall correctly. But maybe I'm remembering wrong. On the other hand, then what should be in the AppResources.resx file, and why does the [Xamarin docs](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/advanced/localization/#Adding_Resources) say to do it that way?

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that you told about **NET Standard library**

`ResourceManager.GetString` started giving null for new entries after moving from **PCL** to **.NET Standard**

I also observed that the file **AppResources.Designer.cs** disapeared from the Solution Explorer (but I don't know how, was still considered) and, in the VS res editon of **AppResources.resx**, **Access Modifier** was `No Code Generation`.

Here is what I did to fix that:

- I double-clicked on **AppResources.resx** and set **Access Modifier** to Internal or Public
- In .NET Standard you may no longer be able to see "View Code" from resx files; so, I righ-clicked on AppResources.resx-> Open With -> Source Code Editor and copy the new created entries to all the others *.fr (also *.nl in your case) ...

**NOTE**

1. In the context menu you should see **Run Custom Tool**. You may need to delete the old **AppResources.Designer.cs** and do "Run Custom Tool"
2. Don't forget to clear the solution (or olny UWP and the standard library), close VS, delete all `.\bin` and `.\obj` and restart VS. This to ensure your issue is fixed or not using the very very new generated true code :)